# Can a http client using XMPP interact directly with jitsi videobrigdge server?

Tags: http, xmpp, jitsi, prosody-im

I want to implement a cross platform chat app. I want to use XMPP and  I know that XMPP's BOSH extension is used for instant messaging.

However, I also need a video conference and audio conference abilities. [jitsi](https://jitsi.org/) does that actually. It uses [prosody](https://prosody.im/) for instant messaging which actually uses BOSH. And jitsi uses jitsi-videobridge(which can be found in the same link I attached previously) for audio and video conference capabilities.

Here comes my question. Can an http client using XMPP protocol can talk to a jitsi videobridge server directly without needing any other requirements. I'm confused because in the official website of jitsi, it is written that it is compatible with WEBRTC. I really couldn't grasp the idea of WEBRTC. Does WEBRTC compatible mean that http client can talk to server without any other needs or XMPP protocol is the same basis for both?

Any help or corrections appriciated.

Comment: WebRTC is a realtime media stack built into web browsers that allows doing audio/video calls without having to install anything; it's completely unrelated to XMPP.  WebRTC doesn't specify a signaling protocol/channel though so implementors must choose their own and the Jitsi team chose to use XMPP.  Jitsi clients use XMPP to exchange information necessary for media side as well as using a MUC to communicate within the conference (including the built-in chat)...

Comment: I'm on the Jitsi team but unfortunately not much of an XMPP expert so can't help too much with that, but you could checkout the XMPP-communication related logic in the lib-jitsi-meet repo [here](https://github.com/jitsi/lib-jitsi-meet).  Particularly in the modules/xmpp directory.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications, I am more clear about it know. However, trials of days long, I am not able to integrate ofmeet(openfire version of jitsi-videobridge + jitsi meet, videobridge normally works on prosody not openfire) into openfire. Everything works fine but jitsi meet client can't load.I guess I have a websocket problem but I am not able to figure it out.(I used writer's version for websocket(https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/60934), they know official release is broken for openfire 4.1.4 and above and they fixed it but not yet released officially)